# Where to negate logical expression in bash

Tags: bash

How do you negate a test in bash if you want to combine multiple tests?

The code is

```
if ! [ $(pgrep Xvfb) ] || [ ! -v DISPLAY ]; then
    echo starting xvfb
    mkdir -p /tmp/xvfb
    Xvfb :1 -fbdir /tmp/xvfb > /tmp/xvfb_output 2>&1 &
    export DISPLAY=:1
fi
```

It is supposed to be sourced and to start Xvfb if not already running.
Previously, it lacked the `|| [ ! -v DISPLAY ]` part to check the existence of said variable.

To negate a test, you could do either `! [ ... ]` or `[ ! ... ]`, which both seem to work.

**Is the reasoning correct that you should use `[ ! ...]` because it is inside the test and thus clearer (and a bit more efficient)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter where you put the negation in terms of efficiency. As for readability, you could write your `if` statement like this:

`if ! (test "$(pgrep Xvfb)" -a -n "${DISPLAY:+1}"); then`

This way you have only one negation on one test.

I agree with you that

`if ! [ $(pgrep Xvfb) ] || [ ! -v DISPLAY ]; then`

is ambiguous and

`if [ ! $(pgrep Xvfb) ] || [ ! -v DISPLAY ]; then`

is not.

Comment: Rewriting as AND clause had not occurred to me. Thank you. Do you consider the `if ! (test...` line more readable than the `if [ ! ...` line?

Comment: @user Yes, I actually prefer the `test expr` expression to `[ expr ]` in general. I find the brackets heavy in this case, especially because the end bracket is by my experience never useful as a clue to detect the end of a condition in shell scripting. Of course, that is only my opinion. :-) Use brackets if you prefer this notation.

Comment: `[ $(pgrep Xvfb) ]` is a mistake in and of itself. You are *hoping* that the output from `pgrep` will be a valid non-empty string so that the `[ ... ]` test passes. But that's not reliable or a good idea. Luckily (because it is sane) `pgrep` has meaningful return codes. So to test that it found something you want `if pgrep Xvfb &>/dev/null; then echo "do something now that we found Xvfb"; fi`. For this case that would be `if ! pgrep Xfvb &>/dev/null || [ ! -v DISPLAY ]; then ....; fi`. I'll also note this runs Xvfb more than once if `DISPLAY` gets unset which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner Agreed, that's why I used `"$(pgrep Xvfb)"` in my suggestion, but I forgot to add a remark on this in my answer. I also modified the second test as the `-v` option for `test` won't work with all shells.

Comment: Your suggestion also used `-a` which is deprecated and used a sub-shell which was unnecessary.

Comment: @EtanReisner I didn't know about the binary option `-a` of `test` being deprecated actually. I never used any implementation that does not support this syntax.

Comment: It isn't that things don't support it. It is that it was historically poorly specified and could more easily be by user input so POSIX considers it obsolete at this point (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16).